# Big commerce auth flow missing Context having store hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigcommerce

I am using omniauth-bigcommerce gem

Response is getting from big commerce after auth callback process. In the params context is missing which is needed to get access token through post request

```
{"code"=>"nf0cayio41l0ws4vtpfyl18hwbd3v13",
 "scope"=>"users_basic_information store_v2_products store_v2_information",
 "state"=>"b599054a60ecb7d7a8f0987bef3eb2c29b5631c40266b92c",
 "controller"=>"home",
 "action"=>"after_authantication_create",
 "provider"=>"bigcommerce"}
```

**EDIT:**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :bigcommerce, "MY_KEY", "MY_SECRET",
           {
             scope: "users_basic_information store_v2_products store_v2_information",
             client_options: {
                               site: 'login.bigcommerce.com';
                             }
           }
end
```

Comment: Post your code and related info like gems (may be `omniauth-bigcommerce` etc) and error, if any

Comment: yes I am using omniauth-bigcommerce gem

Comment: Can you clarify the process you are following for generating the Auth Callback Request from Bigcommerce?  Are you creating a URL in the following format:

`https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ovfn0sn8wbno5n4yjev02aobr7nif33333&context=stores/ec657a&redirect_uri=https://domain.com/auth&response_type=code&scope=store_v2_customers_read_only`

and then following that link, logging into your store and approving your app?  The above process is not the expected way to generate an Auth Callback Request and can have strange results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bigcommerce have just moved to the basic auth to omini auth , So still there are some issues with there API's. I have contacted them and got reply that they will fix all issues soon.

Comment: Good, helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks OKAY. I think you are expecting the desired response at wrong place.

In your callback action, you can get the desired token as follow:

```
  auth = request.env['omniauth.auth'] # All required details are in this Auth Hash
  token = auth[:credentials][:token]
```

You may want to have a look on [Auth hash Schema](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema) for better understanding.

Comment: you are right but still missing the hash code from response

Comment: Didn't get you. Please elaborate with corresponding code

Comment: I want to use omni auth flow of authorize for big commerce.So that when user comes to my application he can click and can authanticate my big commerce application for his store. After  authorization I will get access token for the user and can fetch orders , and can do more stuff.